# Set NTP - Time Manually

Tags: linux, time, debian, ntp

Is it possible to configure the Time of an NTP Server manually, we wannt our own time-system for our Community but i cant figure out how to set the time of our ntp by hand

Comment: What version of NTP, what version of OS, etc.   Also show what you've tried...

Comment: ntpd 4.2.6p5   |   8.9 (jessie) | and i tried nothing more so far than look up the config file but there is no way to change the time manually

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? in a comment below you say 'to distribute our own Time 13:37 should be our 0:00 but we dont wannt to use time Zones' is that an offset of -13h37min? You need to explain your use-case a little better. Take a moment to read the [help] as well.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly apt-get install ntp then `nano /etc/ntp.conf` [image]

then delete '#'

[image]

We specify which ip addresses or network the ntp server will serve by removing the # sign at the beginning of the restrict line and entering our own ip and netmask
then ctrl+x and exit.

```
/etc/init.d/ntp stop

/etc/init.d/ntp start
```

thats enough

[image]

then u should control your system

```
systemctl restart ntp
```

[image]

This is the setup and configuration of our server. After that we can use the group policy, dhcp server to distribute our ntp server settings to our clients, or we can manually enter the client. If we make sure that the time zone setting on the client side is correct, we can use our service without any problems.

Comment: too nice of you but thats not what we wannt we wannt pretty much to distribute our own Time 13:37 should be our 0:00 but we dont wannt to use time Zones